# Oracle SQL: Need to generate a query that accumulates time in service by position

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that records an employee's position history.  It's fairly simple:

(Yes, I know this app is using strings to store dates, bugs me like crazy but it's what I have to work with).

`create table pos_hist (emp_id varchar2(10), pos_id varchar2(10), start_date varchar2(8), stop_date varchar2(8));`

This company will often swap people back and forth between positions.  Then someone may leave and come back and be put in the same or a different position.

Stop date is recorded as '00000000' for a current position incumbent.

The requirement is for each employee to generate a timeline of earliest date and last date that an employee was in each position.   Even if that position was separated by a period of non service.

For example, let's say we have the following data:

```
insert into pos_hist values ('0000000001', '0001', '20010101', '20010401');
insert into pos_hist values ('0000000001', '0002', '20010401', '20010701');
insert into pos_hist values ('0000000001', '0001', '20010701', '20011001');
insert into pos_hist values ('0000000001', '0002', '20011001', '20011101');
insert into pos_hist values ('0000000001', '0002', '20050101', '20050601');
insert into pos_hist values ('0000000001', '0001', '20050601', '00000000');
```

The required output would be 5 lines for this employee, merging the two consecutive periods of service in a particular position into one line:

```
0000000001    0001    20010101    20010401
0000000001    0002    20010401    20010701
0000000001    0001    20010701    20011001
0000000001    0001    20011001    20050601
0000000001    0001    20050601    00000000
```

My thought was to try using the RANK() function to generate a ranked list and then selecting from that min(start_Date) and max(stop_date) for each (with a case to handle the 0000000 for the current position but I haven't been able to come up with the correct partition / order by to generate the correct ranks.

I've tried variations on

```
select employee_id, position_id, start_date, stop_date,
       rank() over (partition by start_date, position_id order by  start_date) p_rank
from pos_hist;
```

But it just isn't returning what I want.

I keep getting everything ranked "1" or sorted in the wrong order and I'm tired of bashing my head against the wall on this one.

Anyone able to offer some insight here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  Your sample data "tiles" perfectly, meaning that there are no gaps or overlaps.

In this case, the "islands" can be determined using the difference of row numbers:

```
select emp_id, pos_id, min(start_date), max(stop_date)
from (select ph.*,
             row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by start_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by emp_id, pos_id order by start_date) as seqnum_2
      from pos_hist ph
     ) ph
group by emp_id, pos_id, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=667bb5ecf5464e963e76fd7940b4564d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: In that example it might tile perfectly, I don't know that it's always going to do that :)  Stop date in one position might be  day before start date in the next etc.  I'll have to toy with it a little and see.  Thanks for that though, I'll go play.

Comment: @SJWales . . . There are alternative ways of expressing the logic.  This is the simplest method that works on the data you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is what `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` is designed for:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   pos_hist
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY emp_id
  ORDER     BY start_date
  MEASURES
    FIRST( pos_id )     AS pos_id,
    FIRST( start_date ) AS start_date,
    LAST( stop_date )   AS stop_date
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( consecutive_pos_id+ )
  DEFINE
    consecutive_pos_id AS  FIRST( pos_id ) = pos_id
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pos_hist ( emp_id, pos_id, start_date, stop_date ) AS
SELECT '0000000001', '0001', '20010101', '20010401' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0000000001', '0002', '20010401', '20010701' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0000000001', '0001', '20010701', '20011001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0000000001', '0002', '20011001', '20011101' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0000000001', '0002', '20050101', '20050601' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0000000001', '0001', '20050601', '00000000' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> EMP_ID     | POS_ID | START_DATE | STOP_DATE
> :--------- | :----- | :--------- | :--------
> 0000000001 | 0001   | 20010101   | 20010401 
> 0000000001 | 0002   | 20010401   | 20010701 
> 0000000001 | 0001   | 20010701   | 20011001 
> 0000000001 | 0002   | 20011001   | 20050601 
> 0000000001 | 0001   | 20050601   | 00000000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f7b5986e1aa5de42b17cee9a3efa548d)*

Comment: Thank you very much.   Both your answer and the answer provided by Gordon seem to get me the result set I need.   I wish I could have given you both the check for correct answer, but since Gordon responded first and both were correct answers, I gave it to him instead.